# Can I access the data from SQLAlchemy database writing a separate backend on Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

Consider that someone wrote a user backend. So the backend consists of users and their houses. The backend uses SQLAlchemy to store the users and their houses (so a user can have multiple houses). Both users and houses have their unique IDs.

Now, I want to write a separate backend in Django Rest framework in order for the users to be able upload the house pictures for their houses.

Will it be possible to do that? To be more specific, my thought is to connect to that SQLAlchemy database and whenever the user types a url (.../user34/house55/) my code triggers my model which retrieves the Token and extracts the user ID and house ID and gets ready for the POST from that specific user. So when the user uploads the image, my backend simply saves a new field in SQLAlchemy. Or would that be impossible as the user backend does not have a field for that?

Comment: SqlAlchemy is an ORM just like django ORM. The data will be stored in a db like mysql or postgresql. And Yes you can access the table created by SqlAlchemy in Django as Django Model. You need to specify `db_table=<table_name>` in a django model Meta options.
For Reference see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#db-table)

Comment: @yogkm Okay I see. So it does not matter that the previous existing backend has that field or not, I just add that extra field myself when I write the backend in Django? Do I need to add the user fields too? I think you answered to my question.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).